# Title of chapter

Tags: sectioning

Can you please tell me that why in the output pdf file title "Chapter" is written two times i.e
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
but I wrote only "chapter 2" in the code.

[image]

Comment: Try with `\chapter{2}`. The chapter name and number are automatically added.

Comment: just to clarify you after the \section(The LHC and the ATLAS detector} new paragraph is started.

Comment: that is the way LaTeX works.

Comment: Really OnTopic: You will save much time if you read just 4-5 pages of any available tutorial/book/resource about... TypicallyOnTopic: Use just `\chapter{}` and the numbers will be placed automatically...

Answer (score 2):

In the standard classes, \chapter already inserts the word "Chapter" followed by the chapter number before the chapter title you provide. If you don't want that, and don't need a table of contents, you can use `\chapter*{My Chapter Title}`.

If you need a table of contents, but don't want the word "Chapter" to be added automatically, you can add (in the preamble)

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
```

and then use `\chapter{My Chapter Title}`.

But avoid putting the chapter number in your chapter title: one of the advantages of Latex is that all the tedious bookkeeping of chapter and section numbers (and keeping it all synchronised with e.g. the table of contents) is done for you.

If you don't like the standard formatting of the chapter and section titles, one document class that comes with quite a range of chapter styles is the 'memoir' class (and it has documented exemples of how to create your own style). But there are other ways of modifying the titles to your liking.